# I can not access my WordPress dashboard because of a plugin called "Clef"

Tags: wordpress, web, authentication

I have activated a Two Factor Authentication sing in method called "Clef" on my WordPress based site. It turns out they have shut "Clef" down on July 2017.

The problem is that when I want to sign in to my WordPress dashboard, I get a "loading clef login" page and nothing happens.

How can I remove it?

Comment: Do you have your own FTP Login credentials? If so, you  can login via software such as FileZilla and remove the relevant Plugin Folder. I will provide a fuller, step by step answer, as soon as I am on a computer (an hour or so), unless someone does it beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (and possibly the only) way will be going to the FTP server, going to `wp-content/plugins/` directory and removing `clef` directory (or whatever is the name of this plugins directory name).

WordPress will disable this plugin automatically, if it doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 3):

As promised, here are the steps you could take:

**Option A:**

1. Download [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client)
2. Log in, using the Login Credentials supplied by your Registrar/Hosting Provide
3. Go to: `/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins`
4. If `/httpsdocs/` is not there, simply head to `/wp-content/plugins`
5. Find the name of your Plugin (Presumably 'Clef') and simply delete the Folder.

**Option B:**

I am not sure who is providing your Domain/Hosting but you can always login via your Domain/Hosting Control Panel and delete the Folder from the Web files, that way.

If I were you, stick to Option A.  Not only is it the most universal but something I would advise getting an understanding for, since you could use FileZilla to backup your Web Files in the future.

Any problems, drop me a Comment and I will help you along the way, if needs.

Comment: Dear Craig, thank you very much for your answer. It was very helpful.

Comment: No worries.  Glad I could help you.  As good practice, always make a backup of your website; before performing major changes.  Your backup should consist of both your Web Files and your MySql Database.  Good luck with your venture! :-)